# Why is that some other 3rd party libraries wont work inside a mat-tab component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

First iv'ed been implementing quilljs as a rich text editor on my application inside a mat-tab and there was a syntax error occurred.

When i place the element outside the mat-tab component the editor works perfectly fine.

Now, I replace it to tinymce editor an open source version. Again i still got a syntax error occurred but when placing it outside mat-tab it is working fine.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
```

Is this a bug? Anyone came across this issue? How can we prevent mat-tab from breaking 3rd party libraries?

Comment: I was able to solve this issue by using lazy loading of mat-tab found in the doc which depend on angular6 so you need to upgrade if you use angular2/4/5.